# How to Set Visualforce Page PDF No Pagination

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning

Is it possible to disable PDF auto pagination in VF page PDF ?

Like this
[image]

Comment: PDF rendering engine used is [Flying Saucer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/flying-saucer/) which supports CSS 2.1 - you might want to ask this question on stackoverflow

Comment: _(untested)_ CSS like this `@page {
  size: 8in 1000in;
}` see https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#page-size-prop (Flying Saucer supports this CSS 3 property)